# moving background image horizontally

Tags: javascript, jsbin

[My Game](http://jsbin.com/vazucovoca/1/edit?html,js,output)

I made a game and all the images included in it is moving vertically. I would like to know how to move it horizontally.

Comment: You game is currently not functioning, also you should include relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The jsbin you linked does not work on my computer, so there might be other problems.

Anyway, to make the Background move horizontally in your game, you find the function `function Background()`, and change this.y asignations to `this.x` (for example, `this.y += this.speed` would become `this.x += this.speed`).